# RxSwift pod issue in Xcode12

Tags: ios, xcode, rx-swift

I am using RxSwift pod in project. It is working fine till now. I have upgraded RxSwift to latest version(RxSwift '6.0.0') and installed pod file.
After installing the latest RxSwift pod I am unable build the app. I am getting so many errors.

Please help me to fix and also let me know is their any dependency or limitations to use latest RxSwift pod.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide a few examples of the "so many errors" you are getting, Many of the operators were renamed, but the old ones still exist with deprecation warnings, not errors...